# 'Qt5' not found in CMake project with vcpkg static export

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-code, cmake

I wanna create a project use VSCode+CMake+VCPKG(VTK+Qt5)
And I still want to share my VCPKG depencies with teammate.
So I export VCPKG.

When I try to `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)` problem happened

```
By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:
    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

And I try to `set(Qt5_DIR "{vckpg_root_path}\installed\x64-windows\share\qt5")`

There is no Qt5Config.cmake to let cmake read!!

[image]

That's what inside.

**How can I exactly use Qt5
And set include file directories in cmakelist.txt?**

Comment: Qt5Config is usually under the lib/cmake folder. I usually tend to build QT myself so not sure about vcpkg version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found how to make it
Add script in CMALKELIST.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
set(VCPKG_DIR "C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-windows"
      CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      CACHE STRING "")
```

and to add Qt compoment, cause Qt package is divide to many bit.
So use `COMPOMENTS` with Qt package you want to include.

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)
if (${Qt5Core_FOUND})
    message("Found Qt " ${Qt5_VERSION})
else()
    message("Couldn't find Qt")
endif()
```